# How to resolve Nullpointerexception error?

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-gradle-plugin, bottomnavigationview

My project was working all fine then the gradle build started showing 2 of this error:

```
Nullpointerexception: null
```

I thought about finding the spot of the error from the monitor by running it in the emulator but all it is showing is a sea of AAPT errors rather than nullpointers one.
[image: All the errors]

I have tried deleting the .gradle & .idea folders, also I don't see any problem with any objects that's causing this error and none of the fixes helps.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Now the monitor on emulation shows error `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView cannot be cast to com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx` in the Home activity. I'm so confused [image]

[image]

Comment: Is there nothing that has more details in the gradle console (please add these apt errors in text to your question: [edit])? restarting android studio or cleaning the build sometimes helps. If not, try running the gradle build from the command line `gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace` which should show you more info about the NPE.

Comment: can you please close the Gradle Console so I could see the error in logcat?

Comment: @zapl now its not showing any apt errors rather bottomnavigationview error on emulation. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MeanCoder thats all in the logcat

Comment: Your layout has a bottonnavigationview from the support library but the code expects one from some library. Check the layout xml for that activity https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/blob/master/README.md#getting-started

Comment: @zapl thannks bud i got it working on the emulator but the event log during the gradle build still shows the 2 errors. Is that negligible ?